# In flutter how to use WebRTC to stream video to RTMP?

Tags: flutter, webrtc, rtmp, live-streaming, amazon-ivs

I have tried lot of research.. let me know how to live stream without camera view using RTMP server.I have tried with flutter_live,flutter_webrtc and rtmp_publiser plugin's.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to describe your use scenaio:

1. What do you want to use to publish to RTMP server? OBS? FFmpeg? Chrome? Android? iOS?
2. What do you want to play the stream from RTMP server? VLC? Chrome? Android ? iOS?
3. Why do you need WebRTC?
4. What did you connect the camera to?
5. What app or platform like you want? YouTube? Twitter? Discord? Zoom? TikTok?

Conflict question, because WebRTC always use camera:

- `In flutter how to use WebRTC to stream video to RTMP?`
- `how to live stream without camera`

Didn't get you.

Comment: I want to live stream with rtmp server using video output.

Comment: Please try to describe your use scenaio:
1. What do you want to use to publish to RTMP server? OBS? FFmpeg? Chrome? Android? iOS?
2. What do you want to play the stream from RTMP server? VLC? Chrome? Android ? iOS?
3. Why do you need WebRTC? 
4. What did you connect the camera to?
5. What app or platform like you want? YouTube? Twitter? Discord? Zoom? TikTok?

Comment: The RTMP in flutter is totally outdated and it has very limited documentation. I have struggle a lot with it. Kindly use kotlin for this.